# C ++ exit code 3221225477

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to run a simple C++ program on pointers but the output I am getting is "**[Finished in 5.55s with exit code 3221225477]**". The Norton Data Protector on my system is blocking the file execution (I guess) but I don't know why? I deactivated the Data Protector but nothing changed. Kindly someone please take a look at the my code and explain to me, what is going on here? Thank You

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {   
        int x;
        int * ptr ;
        *ptr = x ; 
        cout<<ptr;
    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `3221225477` = `0xC0000005` = `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. What is `*ptr = x` expected to do?

Comment: None of the variables you're using are initialized.

Answer (score 6):

The **problem** is that the variable `x` is uninitialized and you're using  the value of an uninitialized variable which leads to **undefined behavior.** Same goes for variable `ptr`, it is also uninitialized and dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior.

```
*ptr = x ;//undefined behavior because first x is uninitialized and you're using x and second ptr is also unitialized and you're dereferencing ptr
```

You should do:

```
int x = 0;
int *ptr = &x;//now ptr is a pointer pointing to variable x
```

For this very reason it is advised that:

> always initialize built in types in local/block scope otherwise they have **indeterminate value** and using/accessing  that value leads to **undefined behavior**

UB(short for undefined behavior) means anything can happen Including but not limited to **access violation error**. Check out [What does access violation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071757/what-does-access-violation-mean).

Comment: UB doesn't really explain the access violation error.

Comment: @Evg UB means anything can happen Including but not limited to **access violation error**. Check out [What does access violation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071757/what-does-access-violation-mean)

Comment: "but not limited to" - yes, that's the reason why UB doesn't *explain* anything. Here the explanation comes from how virtual memory works not from UB.